# Google redirected blog no longer getting found easily

Tags: blogger, google-plus

I found to my surprise that when I published a new post on my blog (hosted by Googles blogspot.com) and then searched for the title in Google Search it would show up as one of the top hits almost immediately.

But now I have the post redirecting to my own subdomain, and even though behind the scenes it is still hosted by Google the blog is not coming up in the search results, although a link to the page from my GooglePlus account is coming up (but this is not as good for me as an actual link to the blog itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had `example.blogspot.com` and it is now at `blog.example.com`, it will take some time for Google to update it's index for the new URLs. Some of the posts will be updated in days, some will take a few weeks.

Comment: i dont mean existing posts using old url, thats okay. I mean new posts not showing up at all

Comment: The same principle applies for new posts.  Give it a little time, and you are likely to find your new url is indexed as quickly as the old one was.

Comment: well i hope so or Im going to regret making the change